# Why does Get-ChildItem fail on accessing a directory on a different machine on PowerShell script executed by task scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, scheduled-tasks

I am working on the following PowerShell script that has as purpose to collect and look for errors in log files.

The PowerShell script is the following:

```
$date = Get-Date -format dd.MM.yy
$time = Get-Date -format HH:mm
$fileout = @()
$outputfile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\logged_error.txt"

$computers = 'pc1','pc2'

foreach ($computer in $computers){

#LOG 1
$log = @(Get-ChildItem -Path ("\\$computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Logcollector\diagnose\*").ToString() -Include "SUITE_*" |Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending|Select-Object -Index 0)

if (($log| Get-Content -tail 14|Select-String -Pattern "WARNING","ERROR").Matches)  {
    $outputLine = "$computer contains one or more errors in last 14 lines of file on date $date time $time"
    $fileout += $outputLine
}
else {
    $outputLine = "$computer contains no errors in last 14 lines of file on date $date time $time"
    $fileout += $outputLine
}

#LOG 2 and LOG 3 same structure as LOG 1

}$fileout|Out-File -FilePath $outputfile -Encoding ascii
```

The script works fine when I run it manually via cmd or ISE but does not work if I run it through the task scheduler.

The task properties are the following:

```
General
run as NT-Authority\SYSTEM 
run with highest privilege
Actions
start a program 
powershell.exe
-file "c:\temp\test.ps1"
C:\Temp>powershell.exe -file "c:\temp\test.ps1"
```

Unfortunately by local policy the task scheduler do not memorize the user and password.
I try to change the user with the builtin\Administrator and the task runs fine as far as a user is logged in the PC. But if no one is logged, the `Get-ChildItem` fail and the if statement will skip comparison to give the else condition and give a file with a false negative.

How can I go around this problem is a couple of days that I banging around this script?

I tried to wrap the script in a batch file.
I tried to tweak the script by using the `invoke-command` and `New-PSSession`.
I tried to run the script from a client computer from the host computer.

Comment: The Task Scheduler need to be run using an account.  The default is no account which doesn't have an environment.  See following : https://thesleepyadmins.com/2020/01/28/check-scheduled-task-for-run-as-account-powershell/

Comment: I follow the instruction on the link and the script run under the account Administrators

Comment: It may be the dollar sign.  Try following : $log = @(Get-ChildItem -Path ("\\$computer\" + 'c$\Program Files (x86)\Logcollector\diagnose\*').ToString() -Include "SUITE_*" |Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending|Select-Object -Index 0)  Use single quote to allow c$ to pass to remote machine.

Comment: Why the extra `.ToString()`? ( that will ruin the **objects** received by Get-ChildItem) and instead of `-Include "SUITE_*"` I would use `-Filter "SUITE_*"`. Adding switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem should also help because you don't want directories in the result too.

Comment: Change to `$log = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Logcollector\diagnose\*" -Filter "SUITE_*" -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Just Try your solution @Theo it still has same issue but at least now when I run it without task scheduler the performance are way better

Comment: Are you sure Get-ChildItem is the problem? I would say it is the path in `$outputfile` (some users desktop) where the account running the task has no permission to write to.. Also, if `$computer` is a 32-bit machine, there won't be any folder `Program Files (x86)`..

Comment: Yes, fairly positive I run some tests on the rest of the script and it is fine. the only fail came from Get-childitem combined with the task scheduler